# How can I get the last commit SHA of a branch that happened before squash and merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, squash

I have a branch where I then created a pull request and did a Squash and merge which generated a new commit SHA and merged to master.

Issue is I want to use that SHA from master `qe55a1a` to retrieve the last SHA on the branch `ca10b2d`, right before the squash and merge.

Is there a git command that can be used to get `ca10b2d` from `qe55a1a` programmatically - Given qe55a1a, ca10b2d must be returned.

```
Branch A 
ca10b2d - last commit
qe55a1a - squash and merge commit

Master
qe55a1a - squash and merge commit
```

I know if I had of done merge commit, i'd have a second parent commit that could be used.  That's what i'm after but for squash and merge.

Comment: Check your `git reflog` - and **do not** run `git gc` nor any other commands that might affect or erase non-referenced objects in the git store (as those objects _are_ your now-deleted commits).

Comment: I wondered about git reflog.  I need to be able to do this programmatically though.  Given `qe55a1a`, `ca10b2d` must be returned... or whatever the commits are for the next branch and so on

Comment: You didn't say anything about "doing this programmatically" in your question. Please update your post to accurately describe what it is you're doing.

Comment: What is your underlying goal? Why do you want to retrieve the old commits? If you can tell us the larger context we might be able to suggest other solutions to your overall problem. For example: how to avoid squashing; how to add metadata when squashing; how to keep a branch around for the original commits; or why you don't actually need the original commit hashes.